# Questions of commutative algebra proposition2.8 from Atiyah

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Proposition 9.2. Let A be a Noetherian local domain of dimension one, m its
maximal ideal, $ k = \frac{A}{m}$ its residue field. Then the following are equivalent:
i)A is a discrete valuation ring;
ii) A is integrally closed,
iii)  m is a principal ideal,
iv) $dim_k\left( \frac{m} {m^2}=1 \right)$
v) Every non-zero ideal is a power of m;
vi) There exists $x \in A $ such that every non-zero ideal is of the form $\left(x^k\right)$,$k\ge0$

Proof. Before we start going the rounds, we make two remarks:
(A) If a is an ideal $\neq 0$,(1) , then a is m-primary and $a \supseteq m^n$ for some n.
For r(a)= m, since m is the only non-zero prime ideal; now use (7.16).
(B) $m^n\neq m^{n+1}$ for all $n\ge 0$. This follows from (8.6).\

iii)=>iv). By (2.8) we have $dim_k$ (m/$m^2$) $\le1$, and by remark (B) m/$m^2 \neq 0$.\

I can't understand iii)=>iv). Could someone explain more to me?
Also, could someone explain more about proposition2.8 to me? I am confused about the sentence "whose images form a basis of this vector space". Could someone explain the proposition2.8 statement more to me? (Or even the proof of proposition2.8, if it is necessary to understand proposition2.8)

Comment: iii) implies iv) immediately since if $m=(x)$ is principal, $m/m^2$ is generated as a $k$-vector space by $x+m^2$. This is because every element of $m/m^2$ looks like $rx+m^2$, and if $r \in m$ then $rx \in m^2$ so $rx+m^2=m^2$ is the zero vector. If $r\not \in m$, then $r$ is a unit and so $r+m$ is a nonzero element of $k$ and $r+m$ acts on $m/m^2$ via $x+m^2 \mapsto rx+m^2$. Thus $\dim_k m/m^2 \le 1$ since $\{x+m^2\}$ is a spanning set. But since $x+m^2\neq 0$, it must then be a basis of $m/m^2$. I believe this is the images forming a basis part of the proposition you mention.

Comment: Sorry, 1. Why the element in m/$m^2 \neq 0$ is of the form rx+$m^{2}$?
2. Moreover, could you explain more about what do you mean r+m acts on r+$m^{2}$?
3. Just to confirm, $dim_k$ (m/$m^2$)  here is still the longest length of prime ideals, right?

Comment: 1. Elements of $m/m^2$ are images of elements in $m$ inside the ring $A/m^2$, so they must look like $rx+m^2$ where $r \in A$ as $m=(x)$, so every element of $m$ looks like $rx$ for some $r\in A$. 2. This is just the vector space structure -- by acts, I mean acts via scalar multiplication. 3. No, $\dim_k$ is the dimension as a $k$-vector space, not dimension as a ring. $m/m^2$ is not a (commutative, with unit) ring to which the topological definition of dimension as chains of prime ideals applies.

Comment: 1. Refer to your response1, Why m/$m^2 $ is a vector space? What is the homomorphism refer to the m/$m^2$? Why elements of m/$m^2$ are images of elements in m inside the ring A/$m^2$?
2. What is the dimension as a k-vector space? (I mean what's $dim_k$?) Or is there any reference that is useful to help me to understand $dim_k$?
3. You have show the case of $ r \notin m$, but what's the case if $ r \in m$
4. If m/$m^2 $ is not a ring, then how can it be a vector space?

Comment: I think we should not discuss all these details in the comments. We can use this chatroom instead: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141177/walkar

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to enter that chat room, but it said that "the page not found". What time is available for me to enter that chatroom？ Or it's already disappeared?